# How to save an image to file system thats encoded in base64 using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, save, base64, jpeg

```
Object {imageFormat: "image/jpeg", imageB64: "/9j/4AAQ...="}
imageB64: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBD..."
imageFormat: "image/jpeg"
```

I have an image object as above.
I printed it out using

```
console.log(result);
```

It is pretty obvious that it is in base64.

What I want to do is to save this image onto my file system so that i can analyse it. I want to be able to find out the quality and size of this image as it was taken by my webcam and cropped.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968945/convert-base64-png-data-to-javascript-file-objects

Comment: @PawełGłowacz So am I supposed to convert it into a blob object before I can save it?

Comment: Sounds valid to me. Of course you can make image from this base64 and hide in some div and use 3rd party like html2canvas check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668608/generate-an-image-of-a-div-and-save-as/33669243#33669243

Comment: @PawełGłowacz I keep getting an error, it says the download has failed and that there is no file, I did the following.   

`<pre>downloadURI(result, "myImage.jpeg");</pre>  `
`<pre><br/>function downloadURI(uri, name) {  
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
    //after creating link you should delete dynamic link  
    //clearDynamicLink(link);  
}  
</pre>`

Comment: @PawełGłowacz this is result. result = Object {imageFormat: "image/jpeg", imageB64: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAw…rsepzVViSTRRUoxYoZgpwaUsdo57UUVstiBFY5PNFFFIs/9k="}

Comment: Bumps for answers pls

Comment: @PawełGłowacz Need some assistance here